# Input field doesn't focus end of text on mobile

Tags: android, html

So basically, there's this form. It works perfectly in every `browser`, even in the `mobile simulator` in `Chrome`, but as soon as I use a device such as `Samsung` Tablet and open the website in `Android Browser`, there's this particular `textarea` that doesn't let me finish the text when I go back in the field.

So I type a text, I leave the `input` field, I go back but the cursor jumps to the start, which means it doesn't let me finish the text I already started because I can't get to the end. 
Clicking doesn't work, sliding works but jumps straight back to the start.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<label for="DEPOSIT_EXTRA_INFO" class="controllabel">Label<span class="info-trigger not-visible" data-reference="DEPOSIT_EXTRA_INFO"></span></label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<textarea class="form-control" id="DEPOSIT_EXTRA_INFO" data-sim-mask="alphanumeric" data-required="true" name="DEPOSIT_EXTRA_INFO" maxlength="250" tabindex="20">~EXT_BABYACCOUNT.DEPOSIT_EXTRA_INFO~</textarea>

<div class="remaining-textarea pull-right hidden">Number of characters left<span class="remaining-textarea-counter">{0}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was wondering why this issue perfectly describes mine, until I looked at the code. Hey Gregory! :D

Comment: Hopefully you found the bug already ;)